# Python list to string loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

If I want to disassemble a string into a list, do some manipulation with the original decimal values, and then assemble the string from the list, what is the best way?

```
str = 'abc'
lst = list(str.encode('utf-8'))

for i in lst:
    print (i, chr(int(i+2)))
```

gives me a table.

But I would like to create instead a presentation like 'abc', 'cde', etc.

Comment: If you mean you just want them on the same line, you can use print `(i, chr(int(i+2)), end=" ")` to prevent each print being on a new line, but your example 'like 'abc', 'cde', etc.' doesn't match your current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
str_ini = 'abc'
lst = list(str_ini.encode('utf-8'))

str_fin = [chr(v+2) for v in lst]
print(''.join(str_fin))
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string into a list of character values (numbers), you can use:

```
s = 'abc'
vals = [ord(c) for c in s]
```

This results in `vals` being the list `[97, 98, 99]`.

To convert it back into a string, you can do:

```
s2 = ''.join(chr(val) for val in vals)
```

This will give `s2` the value `'abc'`.

If you prefer to use `map` rather than comprehensions, you can equivalently do:

```
vals = list(map(ord, s))
```

and:

```
s2 = ''.join(map(chr, vals))
```

Also, avoid using the name `str` for a variable, since it will mask the builtin definition of `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ord` on the letters to retrieve their decimal ASCII representation, and then `chr` to convert them back to characters after manipulating the decimal value. Finally use the `str.join` method with an empty string to piece the list back together into a `str`:

```
s = 'abc'
s_list = [ord(let) for let in s]
s_list = [chr(dec + 2) for dec in s_list]
new_s = ''.join(s_list)
print(new_s) # every character is shifted by 2
```

Calling `.encode` on the string converts to a `bytes` string instead, which is likely not what you want. Additionally, you don't want to be using built-ins as the names for variables, because then you will no longer be able to use the built-in keyword in the same scope.